# Error trying to load structure with rake db:structure:load, "schema_migration" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations, rails-postgresql

I'm running `rake db:structure:load` but after loading all structure it fails to insert versions at schema_migrations.

Looks like PostgreSQL don't know about recently created tables. Already googled around but haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change or deleted any migrations?

Anyway. You could take a look in the postgres console and try:

to get a list of all databases (to find yours)

```
\list
```

after that

```
\c yourdatabasename_yourenvironment
```

and

```
\dt
```

to see all the tables in the postgres database.